# how to know the exact frame rate and angle of /scan on turtlebot?

Tags: ros, gazebo, laser, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We get an array of floats from the scan topic, but how do I know which number correspond to which angle? In our project, we want know the distance of the obstacle at exactly 0 degree, 90 degree and 180 degree.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271420/how-to-know-the-exact-frame-rate-and-angle-of-/scan-on-turtlebot?/) by [rozoalex](https://answers.ros.org/users/31065/rozoalex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-09-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The good people at Robot Ignite Academy posted an answer to this question, and I assume it is perfectly alright if I post a link to their video walk-thru answering this question, here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RFNNsDI2b6c&t=220s

---

Originally posted by [ezra_schroeder](https://answers.ros.org/users/27707/ezra_schroeder/) with karma: 36 on 2017-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-27**:
Actually, it would be much better if you could give (at least) a summary here, instead of linking to a video that takes 13 minutes to explain this. Future readers that like the more visual approach of video explanations can then still decide to watch it, but for all others, text suffices.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The info at the beginning of the message should tell you the min and max angle, and the angle between readings so you could work out from that which elements in the array correspond to those positions. There are also elements relating to the time

See details of the format of the scan message type here http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2017-09-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3